# Netbeans Background scanning projects loops

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-13, netbeans-14, netbeans-15

I have a problem with Netbeans 15, 14 and 13. The "Background scanning of the projects" process loops between "src/main/java" and "src/test/java". I tried all the solutions in stackoverflow, in particular:

1. Adding the following pattern to "Ignored File Pattern" in Options->Miscellaneous->Files" so as to exclude the build folder:

   ```
   ^(CVS|SCCS|node_modules|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(git|hg|svn|cache|build|DS_Store)$|^Thumbs.db$
   ```
2. Disabling the auto-scanning of sources.

However, the problem persists. The only way to stop the process is to delete the "target" folder manually and that makes me think that maybe something in solution 1. is not working properly. Notice also that during the scanning process features such as auto-complete do not work, hence the IDE is unusable.

Edit:
Removing the folder "classes" in "target" seems stopping the process loop. I'm not sure how to prevent Netbeans for looking in this class.

Comment: I 'm testing this solution, adding the line "-J-Dnetbeans.indexing.recursiveListeners=false" to the netbeans configuration file

Comment: This potentially might be a bug with NetBeans, you should [report an issue](https://netbeans.apache.org/participate/report-issue.html).